# Continuous joint distributions where the ranges of the variables depend on each other

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I've been looking back through old notes and I've come across the following problem:

> $f_{(X,Y)}(x,y)=\begin{cases} \frac{1}{x} &\text{for } 0<y \leq x \leq 1 \\ 0 &\text{otherwise} \end{cases}$
>
> Find the marginal distribution $f_{X}(x)$, $f_{(Y|X)}(y|x)$ and $E[Y|X=x]$.

I'm clearly making a fundamental simple mistake here as I keep getting nonsense answers, and I'm not sure I have good grasp on how to handle these problems when the two variables are ranged dynamically.

For the first bit, I get the following:

$f_{X}(x)=\int_{R_Y}f_{(X,Y)}(x,y)dy=\int^{x}_{0}\frac{1}{x}dy=\big[\frac{y}{x}\big]^{x}_{0}=\frac{x}{x}-\frac{0}{x}=1$ over $0<x\leq 1$

I would expect the marginal distribution of X to feature a $\frac{1}{x}$, as the original distribution doesn't depend on y, hence where my confusion is coming from. My quick sketch of the distribution is:

[Quick sketch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r2EW8.jpg)

Can anyone please suggest where I'm going wrong?

Comment: I am sorry, you were right. The result is simply counter intuitive. I deleted my wrong answer.

Comment: I added a new edit to my answer. Sorry for the delay.

Comment: Is may solution still confusing or could I help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This highlighted answer is wrong**

It should have been deleted. I could not do the deletion because the answer was accepted.

> > With respext to $y$, you integrate over the wrong interval. The right integral (marginal density) is
> >
> > $$\frac1x\int_x^1 dy=\frac{1-x}{x}$$
> >
> > over $0< x\leq 1$.

**Edit 1**

The OP's solution is OK. The result is simply counter intuitive.

**Edit 2**

No, the OP's answer is not counter intuitive. Just take a look at the following figure:

[image]

The fact that $X$'s distribution is uniform over $[0,1]$ can be quite well explained by comparing the volume of the red needle like sky scraper and that of the blue traditional building. The one is thin and high the other one is wide but short. (The exact equality cannot be seen though.)

**Edit 3**

Let's see the meaning of the marginal density of $X$.

The figure above depicts the joint density. The probability that $X\in \text{interval } \color{red} A$ equals the probability  that $(X,Y)\in\text{the triangular red domain } $. This latter probability equals the volume above the red triangular domain and below the surface of the joint density.

The same can be said about the probability that $X\in \text{interval } \color{blue} B$. Now, suppose that the lengths of these two intervals are the same.

The fact that $X$ is uniformly distributed means that in case of intervals of the same length the probability in question is the same.

Is it possible that the blue volume is the same as the red volume? The calculations, at least, tells that. Is it counter intuitive  that the red volume is the same as the blue one?

Not really. Why? Because when the joint density function is high then the domain (red) is small and when the joint density is lower then the domain (blue) is larger (wider). (The area grows proportional to $x$ and the height of the height joint density decreases proportional to $x$. Aaaaand: $x\times \frac1x$ iiiis $1$.

I just hope that this explanation helps understand

(1) The meaning of the marginal density and
(2) that the uniform distribution of $X$ is not that counter intuitive.

Comment: I can see that the $\frac{1}{x}$ can be brought outside because it is effectively a constant, but I thought that because y ranges between 0 below and x above, the limits for the integral should be that. Would you mind explaining why it's between 1 and x?

Comment: It is between x and 1. If you imagine a horzontal line at a certain y then you will see that this line will enter the support of the joint distribution at x and will leave it at 1.

Comment: Ah, yes I see. So even though the range of Y is between 0 and x, as the slice at particular Y only exists between the line y=x and x=1.

Comment: So it actually is $f_{X}=1$? Perhaps my understanding of a marginal distribution is wrong. I was expecting the marginal distribution of X to be slices through the space parallel to the x axis: all of those slices are parallel to Y. I'm confused!

Comment: I will give a third edit.

Comment: Zoli, thanks for all the effort you have put into this. Yes it makes perfect sense, now I can see why it is uniform. Thanks for the helpful edits!